# How to set a default value for the city field in checkout shipping address - magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

I just need to set a default value (with readonly attribute) to the city field in the shipping address section. because the delivery is limited to a particular city at the moment.But the user is free to type any city name in billing address.

In the LayoutProcessor,  getBillingAddressComponent() method i have added :

```
....

....

.... 

'city' => [
    'readonly' =>'readonly',
    'config' => [
    'value' =>'My Custom Value',
    'readonly' =>'readonly',
     'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textC',
        'tooltip' => [
            'description' => __('We deliver items only in selected cities at the moment.'),
        ],
    ],
],

....

....
```

**TextC.html**

```
<input class="admin__control-text" type="text" value="My Custom Value" readonly
data-bind="
    value: value,
    hasFocus: focused,
    valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        maxlength: 255
        readonly: readonly
}"/>
```

Mean time i don't care about editing the core files. Iam working in Magento 2.2

Iam familiar with copying and editing templates in magento 1.X. But i can't find a way to achieve this in Magento 2. Im not sure that im in a right path.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML file seems valid, but in your layout processor you can try something  like this

```
'city' => [
    'config' => [
        'readonly' =>true,
        'value' =>'My Custom Value',
        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textC',
        'tooltip' => [
            'description' => __('We deliver items only in selected cities at the moment.'),
        ],
    ],
],
```

Passing boolean to readonly worked for me